# how to create dynamic submenu using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create a menu. Now i want to create a dynamic submenu. I call an array from database using javascript. Now How to connect array element with the list of submenu using the javascript.

```
enter code here
```

```js
// Request For array from database using function gameNames()
// I define array

var gameName = new Array();

// database responses and get array list in this array.

// I dont know how to code for create a array list as a submenu
```

```html
div id = "bar">
                <ul id = "ul1">
          <li class = "li1"><a href="#" class = "a1">Games</a>
                  <ul id = "submenu"><li></li></ul>     
              
                  </li>
          <li class = "li1"><a href="#" class = "a1">Stake</a></li>
          <li class = "li1"><a href="#" class = "a1">Max Players</a></li>      
               </ul>
          <img src = "css/images/table_menu.png" id = "tm"/>
          <div id = "rmg">Real Money Game</div>
     </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and where is this menu you have created? No source code = nothing to work with. Please update your question with the relevant source code. Thank you.

Comment: @shoaib post source code in order to help you please

Comment: I have normal menu code and sub menu is empty like <li></li>. I check the calling of array from database in console so it suceesfully fetched. Now i have to add that list of element as sub menu of my main menu element. I am using smartFoxserver..

Comment: @NewToJS Sir can you help me ?

Comment: If you want people to help you we need to see the relevant source code. This would include the html for the menu and the call for the array and any other functions you have in relation to the menu. I cannot and will not try help you until you display the relevant code. Thank you.

Comment: @NewToJS now caN YOU SUGGEST ?

Comment: @shoaib Since you lack information I can only make an assumption of the values in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demo. The source code in the `SubMenu()` function is what you will want to use to create the list items from your array.

```js
var gameName=['Game one','Game Two','Game three']
function SubMenu(){
  //Set variable for the submenu ul element
  var Submenu = document.getElementById('submenu');
  //For loop - for each value in the array
  for(var i=0; i<gameName.length; i++){
      //Create new li/List Item
   var Item = document.createElement('li');
      //Set innerHTML for this element
   Item.innerHTML='<a href="#">'+gameName[i]+'</a>';
      //Append new element to the submenu.
   Submenu.appendChild(Item);
  }
//---Demo use Only
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].remove();
//---
}
```

```html
<button onclick="SubMenu();">Create</button>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Games</a>
  <ul id="submenu"></ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Stake</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Max PLayers</a></li>
<ul>
```

If you have any questions about the source code above, leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible. *If this answers your question appreciation is shown by marking it.*

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you Sir. it helps me completely. Only that remove() method did not work. that's work with tag only. i tried to use it with Id so it did not work. i will solve out. and thanks again

Comment: @shoaib You are very welcome. In the source code it does show a commend to show that `remove()` is there for demo purposes only.